# Get Stream from ProjectArea using RTC API 4

Tags: java, rtc, jazz

Hello I have been trying to get the stream name using projectArea.
I have the following parameter:
Repository
IFileItem
WorkItem and its ChangeSets

Is it possible to get it.

Thanks in advance.

Please don't give me a link to the advisor example as I already read it and I couldn't make it.

At this post,it was mentioned the following :
https://jazz.net/forum/questions/49910/how-to-get-an-iconfiguration-from-ichangeset

> There is a hint that is often useful (but not necessarily always
>   correct), hidden in the ILink which serves as the binding between the
>   IChangeSetHandle (source) and the IWorkItemHandle (target). The
>   IItemReference for the source side has a String extraInfo field which
>   can be retrieved via IItemReference#getExtraInfo(). This string will
>   be of the format IWorkspace= which indicates the originating
>   workspace. You can create a handle to the IWorkspace by using
>   IWorkspace.ITEM_TYPE.createItemHandle(suppliedUUID, null).

```
public void testWorkspaceConnection(ITeamRepository repository, IWorkItem workItem) throws TeamRepositoryException, IOException{
       List<ILink> changeSetLinks = (List<ILink>)linkCollection.getLinksById("com.ibm.team.filesystem.workitems.change_set");
       List<IReference> changeSetReferences = new ArrayList<IReference>();

         for (ILink link : changeSetLinks) {
            changeSetReferences.add(link.getSourceRef());
         }

         List<IItemHandle> itemHandles = new ArrayList<IItemHandle>();

         for (IReference reference : changeSetReferences) {
             itemHandles.add((IItemHandle)reference.resolve());
         }

         if(itemHandles.isEmpty()){
             return;
         }

         IItemHandle itemHandle = itemHandles.get(itemHandles.size() - 1);
         IChangeSet changeSet = (IChangeSet)repository.itemManager().fetchCompleteItem(itemHandle, 0, monitor);
         List changes = changeSet.changes();         

         IFileItem fileItem = getLogidiagFile(changeSet, repository);
         // TILL HERE THAT WAS AN EXISTING CODE THAT WAS ALREADY THERE AND IT FETCHES THE REQUIRED FILE.
         //NEXT IS WHAT |'VE ADDED TO BE ABLE TO DETERMINE THE FULL PATH
         String uuid=changeSetReferences.get(changeSetReferences.size()-1).getExtraInfo(); //Here I need to get workspace uuid to be abble to create a connection over as the post said
         IWorkspaceHandle workspaceHandle = (IWorkspaceHandle)IWorkspace.ITEM_TYPE.createItemHandle(UUID.valueOf(uuid), null);

         IWorkspaceManager workspaceManager = SCMPlatform.getWorkspaceManager(repository);
         IWorkspaceConnection workspaceConnection = workspaceManager.getWorkspaceConnection(workspaceHandle,monitor);
```

Exception I get is the following:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid
>   UUID [Workspace=_iibA0GlNEeKd76sMjPDLRA]  at
>   com.ibm.team.repository.common.UUID.valueOf(UUID.java:76)

So am I walking on the right course or there are a better one you can guide me through!

Comment: "I couldn't make it"? I would help if you edited your question with the exact code you tried and the error message you got :)

Comment: Sure .. I've updated my question above.

Comment: Can you replace "`UUID.valueOf(uuid)`" by `_iibA0GlNEeKd76sMjPDLRA`, and see if that work?

Comment: I have replaced it with  IWorkspaceHandle workspace = (IWorkspaceHandle) IWorkspace.ITEM_TYPE.createItemHandle(UUID.valueOf("_iibA0GlNEeKd76sMjPDLRA"), null);

Comment: It didn't throw exception at creation of IWorkspaceHandle but it throws an exception at creating workspaceconnection:com.ibm.team.repository.common.ItemNotFoundException: CRJAZ0215I The following record was not found in the database: com.ibm.team.scm.common.internal.impl.WorkspaceHandleImpl@70c970c9 (stateId: null, itemId: [UUID _iibA0GlNEeKd76sMjPDLRA], origin: <unset>, immutable: <unset>)
 at com.ibm.team.scm.client.internal.WorkspaceManager.getWorkspaceConnection(WorkspaceManager.java:865)

Answer (score 1):

```
 IWorkspaceManager workspaceManager = SCMPlatform.getWorkspaceManager(repository);

IWorkspaceSearchCriteria wsSearchCriteria = WorkspaceSearchCriteria.FACTORY.newInstance();

wsSearchCriteria.setKind(IWorkspaceSearchCriteria.STREAMS);

wsSearchCriteria.setPartialOwnerNameIgnoreCase(projectAreaName);

List <IWorkspaceHandle> workspaceHandles = workspaceManager.findWorkspaces(wsSearchCriteria, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Application.getMonitor());　

IWorkspaceConnection workspaceConnection = workspaceManager.getWorkspaceConnection(workspaceHandles.get(0),Application.getMonitor());
```