# How to show streams in work item editor(Rational Team Concert)

Tags: java, rtc

I want to show all the streams of project area in work item editor.
Streams should be displayed after work item is saved.
I found this link 
[Get Stream from ProjectArea using RTC API 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013137/get-stream-from-projectarea-using-rtc-api-4)
but I am not able to understand it properly.
I really have no idea how to do this. I have been searching for API to get some useful information. Can anyone please guide me with the process of What I should do to get this done.

Comment: Has anyone run the example given on this link https://rsjazz.wordpress.com/2013/09/24/managing-workspaces-streams-and-components-using-the-plain-java-client-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean for "show in work item editor"? You want to insert into a custom attribute a list of all the streams for each work item of a specific type? I don't understand what is your purpose..

Anyway, using SDK and creating a follow-up action you will be able to find out all the streams you need. The point is: how do you want to show them? The easier way is to use a custom string attribute and write the list there. Or maybe you can create a custom link type, but I really don't know if it can work with streams.

Comment: Hi, You have predicted it right. That was my approach to do it. But I am not getting how to fetch streams using server side API. I know how to set value of custom attribute grammatically but i am unaware of the server API which will fetch streams.

Comment: You can search workspace (streams are a particular type of workspace) using com.ibm.team.scm.common.dto.IWorkspaceSearchCriteria togheter with com.ibm.team.scm.common.internal.IScmQueryService findWorkspaces method. With these objects you can search by name, owner, date of creation and other information.